# Why does Python suddenly stop if the input is Yes?

Tags: python, cylindrical

I'm trying to make this program in Python which asks for the surface area and volume of a cylinder. At the end, it asks the user if it wants to calculate volume/surface area. However, if they do type in Yes, nothing happens. What is wrong with my code?

Secondly, I tries using math.pi but it didn't work, what should I do.

The code is long so only scroll down to the important parts:

```
print("Welcome to the volume and surface area cylinder calculator powered by Python!")
response = input("To calculate the volume type in 'vol', to calculate the surface area, type in 'SA': ")
if response=="vol" or response =="SA":
    pass
else:
    print("Please enter a correct statement.")
    response = input("To calculate the volume type in 'vol', to calculate the surface area, type in 'SA': ")

if response=="vol":
    #Below splits 
    radius, height = [float(part) for part in input("What is the radius and height of the cylinder? (e.g. 32, 15): ").split(',')] 
    PI = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286 
    volume = PI*radius*radius*height
    decimal_places = int(input("How many decimal places do you want it to?: "))
    print("The volume of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b3".format(volume, decimal_places))
    verify = input("Do you want to find out the surface area (type in Yes or No): ")
    verify = verify.capitalize
    if verify == "Yes":
       radius, height = [float(part) for part in input("What is the radius and height of the cylinder? (e.g. 32, 15): ").split(',')] 
       PI = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286
       SA = int(2)*PI*radius*radius+int(2)+radius*radius*height
       decimal_places = int(input("How many decimal places do you want it to?: "))
       print("The surface area of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b2".format(SA, decimal_places)) 
    if verify == "No":
        pass

if response =="SA":
    #Below splits 
    radius, height = [float(part) for part in input("What is the radius and height of the cylinder? (e.g. 32, 15): ").split(',')] 
    PI = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286
    SA = int(2)*PI*radius*radius+int(2)+radius*radius*height
    decimal_places = int(input("How many decimal places do you want it to?: "))
    print("The surface area of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b2".format(SA, decimal_places))
    verify = input("Do you want to find out the volume (type in Yes or No): ")
    verify = verify.capitalize
    if verify == "Yes":
        radius, height = [float(part) for part in input("What is the radius and height of the cylinder? (e.g. 32, 15): ").split(',')] 
        PI = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286 
        volume = PI*radius*radius*height
        decimal_places = int(input("How many decimal places do you want it to?: "))
        print("The volume of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b3".format(volume, decimal_places))
    if verify == "No":
        pass
```

Comment: "I tries using math.pi but it didn't work".  You'll need to be more specific when asking for help.

Comment: Also, holy copy-and-paste, Batman!  Even if `math.pi` didn't work, why did you think you needed to redefine `PI` 4 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my tweaked version. It avoids a lot of repetition.

```
from math import pi

print("Welcome to the volume and surface area cylinder calculator powered by Python!")
response = raw_input("To calculate the volume type in 'vol', to calculate the surface area, type in 'SA': ").lower()
while response not in ["vol", "sa"]:
    print("Please enter a correct statement.")
    response = raw_input("To calculate the volume type in 'vol', to calculate the surface area, type in 'SA': ").lower()

radius, height = [float(part) for part in raw_input("What is the radius and height of the cylinder? (e.g. 32, 15): ").split(',')] 

r2 = radius ** 2
SA = 2 * pi * r2 + 2 + pi * radius * height
volume = pi * r2 * height

decimal_places = int(raw_input("How many decimal places do you want it to?: "))

if response=="vol":
    print("The volume of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b3".format(volume, decimal_places))
    verify = raw_input("Do you want to find out the surface area (type in Yes or No): ")
    if verify.lower() == "yes":
       print("The surface area of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b2".format(SA, decimal_places)) 

if response =="sa":
    print("The surface area of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b2".format(SA, decimal_places))
    verify = raw_input("Do you want to find out the volume (type in Yes or No): ")
    if verify.lower() == "yes":
        print("The volume of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b3".format(volume, decimal_places))
```

Comment: Note: raw_input() has been change to input in Python 3.x

Comment: I personally felt that this answer was the best as I could make a direct comparison with mine and see what I could have improved on. Great work Graeme Stuart!

Answer (score 3):

You replaced `verify` with a *method*:

```
verify = verify.capitalize
```

This'll never match either `'Yes'` or `'No'` because it is no longer a string. Call the method instead:

```
verify = verify.capitalize()
```

Note that your test for `"No"` can just be dropped, there is little point in testing for a string then just `pass`ing.

Using `math.pi` instead of `PI` otherwise works just fine:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> radius, height = 32, 15
>>> 2 * math.pi * radius ** 2 + 2 * math.pi * radius * height
9449.910701998098
>>> math.pi * radius ** 2 * height
48254.86315913922
```

Comment: just out of curiousity,i dunno python.in python is "yes" = "YES" ?

Comment: How can I replace all the numbers with math.pi? Secondly, how can I make it exit if verify == "No"? If I try import sys 
sys.exit() it won't work? Thanks again

Comment: @KaushikSivakumar: it is not. Strings are matched case sensitively.

Comment: @TimTimmy: Your program already ends naturally when `'No'` is picked, why would you need to do that explicitly?

Comment: @TimTimmy: The `sys.exit()` didn't work because `str.capitalize == 'No'` was never going to be True.

Comment: @TimTimmy: Using `math.pi` instead of `PI` works just fine for me, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Ok I'll leave it as it is. But when I tried math.pi it wouldn't work? It said math was not defined even if i said import math

Comment: @TimTimmy: Are you sure you spelled things correctly, and restarted your script?